# Netbeans full screen display 2

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I know that `Alt + Shift + Enter` makes netbeans editor go full screen, but the problem is that I want to make this full screen on display 2. I have 2 displays and whenever I move netbeans to attached display screen and press `Alt + Shift + Enter` the full screen happens on built-in display. I would like to go full screen on display 2. Any suggestions?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Can you please tell us which OS you're using as the problem could depend on this.

Comment: @UwePlonus Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a weird issue. Basically you will have to move the IDE to display 2 and then click on the editor to focus and then click on `View -> FullScreen` to make it go full screen.

This will fail if you try to use the shortcut `Alt + Shift + Enter`.